# Whenever I try and add anything to do with wikitable on my wiki when I put "Publish Page" it says forbidden

Tags: mediawiki

The following code does not work when I try to add it to my MainPage as it says it is Forbidden?

{| cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0em 0em 1em 0em; border: 1px solid #1DA0E7;  background: #B3DDF4; width: 100%"

| '''''Alert Text Here'''''

|}

-- Or any code to do with wikitables it just says "Forbidden".

I have tried going into system files but I am scared that I will mess it up.

Comment: Please provde a screenshot or exact error message.

Comment: It is fine now I fixed it.